# Suspicious indentation: This is indented but is not continuing the previous expression

Tags: android, data-binding, android-viewbinding

Android studio showing me this issue with red line below my code line

"Suspicious indentation: This is indented but is not continuing the previous expression (binding.cllInternetA...) (Previous statement here)"

[image: Android studio screenshot while showing issue]

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    //Clear search edit text
    binding.etSearch.text?.clear()

    lookUpNumberVM.isInternetLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it) {
            binding.cllMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.cllInternetAvailability.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            binding.cllMain.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.cllInternetAvailability.visibility = View.VISIBLE
              makeSnackBar(binding.root,"No internet connection")
        }
    }
}
```

my code is above and you can see issue in screenshot attachecd with question.
I will really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: The line of makeSnackBar is indented with two spaces for no reason. Try to delete these two spaces.

Answer (score 46):

Simply Use

```
ctrl+Alt+L
```

and all will be fine.

Comment: Reformat Code? You should explain...

Comment: Yup Android Studio just reformats the code and aligns it perfectly

Comment: Thanks for tip, typical that it would require an three special key fix. All those bright red error lines where irritating.

Comment: wow it was magic <3

Answer (score 1):

As [hata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501958/hata) pointed out in his commentary, it's probably the additional intendation (+2 spaces) of the `makeSnackBar` line. Note, that you can avoid such problems in a general way by ending your code statements with a semicolon, which is usually recommended. This also improves readability. So:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Clear search edit text
    binding.etSearch.text?.clear();

    lookUpNumberVM.isInternetLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it) {
            binding.cllMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
            binding.cllInternetAvailability.visibility = View.GONE;
        } else {
            binding.cllMain.visibility = View.GONE;
            binding.cllInternetAvailability.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
            makeSnackBar(binding.root,"No internet connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Thereby intendation wouldn't play a role anymore (except for readability of course, so keep using intendations) as the compiler has now unambigious information about where a code statement begins and ends.

Comment: A semicolon a the end of a line doesn't improve anything. "The general rule in Kotlin is not to use semicolons." https://kotlincompact.com/no-semicolon.html

Comment: I admit, that even the official https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#semicolons recommends "Omit semicolons whenever possible." However neither here nor in your link it is elucidated why that should be in any way better or at least helpful. On the other side there are good reasons to use semicolons -- readabilty and less error susceptibility.

Answer (score 1):

Help::5

Android studio showing me this issue with red line below my code line

"Suspicious indentation: This is indented but is not continuing the previous expression

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            end=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                them.set(1,end);
                printDiametroPdf(them);
                if (position == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
or
<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This answer is a duplicate to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968783/14267427).